# Accounting format issue when exporting

Tags: crystal-reports, formatting, currency

I have managed to get the report I am working on looking how I would like, setting a column to display using the accounting format which works perfectly when previewing/printing.

However when I try and export this it loses this accounting format and defaulting to it's original format.

*I am using version CR 11.5.10.1263*

**In Crystal Reports**

[image: In Crystal Reports]

**From Exported PDF**

[image: From Exported PDF]

**Setting accounting format**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Strange.

This is a hack, but you could replace the field with two separate fields, one on the left which displays only the currency symbol, and another on the right which displays only the number.